Sort the row by two created_at columns
Let's say i have a table conversation with random sort, like below



created_at_one
created_at_two
message_one
message_two




March, 11
Null
How
one


March, 12
July, 2
Fine
two


July, 1
March,5
Hallo
three


March, 10
Null
Hi
four



There is 2 created_at columns. I want to sort the row by created_at_one, but if created_at_two is not Null, then sort by created_at_two.



created_at_one
created_at_two
message_one
message_two




March, 10
Null
Hi
four


July, 1
March, 5
Hallo
three


March, 12
July, 2
Fine
two


March, 11
Null
How
one



My code like below, but doesn't meet the expectation
ORDER BY message_one.created_at_one DESC NULLS LAST, message_two.created_at_two DESC


You can use COALESCE() to return created_at_two if is it not NULL or to return created_at_one otherwise.
SELECT *, COALESCE(create_at_two, create_at_one) AS created_at
  ORDER BY created_at DESC NULLS LAST;


It also works without NULLS LAST, can you explain why you add it?

I only added it because you used it in your question. It is not relevant for the solution. Unless created_at_one can also be NULL.
